# How to replace dict values with their sum

Tags: python

I have a result set that is in form of a list of `dict`s (sample data below):

```
l = [
  {'id' : 1, 'desc' : 'foo', 'v1' : 1, 'v2' : 2},
  {'id' : 2, 'desc' : 'bar', 'v1' : 3, 'v2' : 4},
  {'id' : 3, 'desc' : 'baz', 'v1' : 5, 'v2' : 6}
]
```

I want to convert this to a form where v1 and v2 are added up and replaced by their summed up value. So the result will look like:

```
[
  {'id' : 1, 'desc' : 'foo', 'v' : 3},
  {'id' : 2, 'desc' : 'bar', 'v' : 7},
  {'id' : 3, 'desc' : 'baz', 'v' : 11}
 ]
```

Please suggest the best way to do this in python 3.2.

**EDIT:**

Here's what I have:

`for d in l:
 d['v'] = d.pop('v1') + d.pop('v2')`

I don't like the part with the `pop()`s and would like to get rid of these and also compress all of it in one line, if possible.

Comment: This shouldn't be too difficult ... Is there a particular spot that you are having trouble with?  If so, please post what your attempt and a description of what is confusing to you.

Comment: You haven't posted valid syntax for creating a dict. What are id, desc etc? Should they be 'id' and 'desc' or are they variables.

Comment: Why don't you like the `pop`s (now that you've edited your Q to exactly match my A!-)...?  How else would you propose to remove existing keys from a dictionary while using their corresponding values -- **exactly** what the `pop` method is for?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about...

```
def sum_v1_v2_into_v(list_of_dicts):
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        v1 = d.pop('v1')
        v2 = d.pop('v2')
        d['v'] = v1 + v2
```

Seems pretty much the obvious approach, right?

If for some totally weird and unexplained reason you want to "compress it into one line, then collapse the last 3 lines to the less-obvious single line:

```
        d['v'] = d.pop('v1') + d.pop('v2')
```

but I fail to see any real advantage -- are you having to pay X per line of code you write, or what?-)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, except for the totally unnecessary double indexing with `'v1'` and `'v2'` -- once to access the value and then another time to pop it out.  The obvious approach is to do both with just **one** indexing.

Comment: Yea, I had the same solution. Should have composed the question properly in the first place. Also have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**In one line:**

[each.update({'v': each.pop('v1')+each.pop('v2')}) for each in l]

**It will return:**

[None, None, None]

but It will update the dict called "l" to

[{'desc': 'foo', 'id': 1, 'v': 3},

{'desc': 'bar', 'id': 2, 'v': 7},

{'desc': 'baz', 'id': 3, 'v': 11}]